# How to read plist file then populate UItableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have been trying read data from a plist file. this is how it is structured

```
|term|detail(string)|
```

my properties :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *terms;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *termKeys;//this is just a array to keep track
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail;
```

this is how I access the detail in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSString *currentTermsName = [termKeys objectAtIndex :[indexPath row]];
                                  [[cell textLabel] setText:currentTermsName];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


    detail = [terms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    NSLog(@" bombs %@",terms[@"Bomb Threats"]);
    return cell;

}
```

and in view didload I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                            pathForResource:@"terms" ofType:@"plist"];
        terms = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
        termKeys = [terms allKeys];
    }
```

It accesses the values , but it store the same one for each object lets say I have 5 different records in plist, if i print detail it displays the same record 5 times.

Once detail is set then I pass it to detialView

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailsegue"]){
        TermsDetailViewController *controller = (TermsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.detailTerm = detail;
    }
}
```

and finaly :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailsegue" sender:self];
}
```

Here is my dictionary : http://pastebin.com/bxAjJzHp

The goal is to pass the detail information to a detailviewcontroller just like a Master/detail sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `detail` variable in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, because this way the value becomes transient: it depends on how the user scrolls through the table, not on what disclosure button the user clicks.

Move this line

```
detail = [terms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` before the call of `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to fix the problem. Now the `detail` is set in response to user's click immediately before the `prepareForSegue:` call, making sure that the correct value is passed to the view controller with the details data.

Comment: thanks for the anwer, your solution is throwing an exception : -`[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa55a40` what could be the issue

Comment: @meda I copied a line from your code, so I suspect that it is something else that's crashing. The call of `objectForKey:` is directed at `terms`, which is `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`. Are you sure that the crash comes from the modified code, and not from the code of the new view controller that does not get a chance to open because of the exception?

Comment: this is my first app , so I may have a couple of mistake, what do you advice

Comment: @meda Add `NSLog(@"%i - %@", indexPath.row, [termKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);` before the `detail = ...` assignment in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and see what gets printed. If everything looks fine, add `NSLog(@"%@", detail);` *after* the `detail = ...` assignment, and see if the second `NSLog` gets called.

Comment: You point out my mistake , I had to changed to an array than i did  detail = [terms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; instead.

Comment: @meda Sure, no problem. You may want to update the question too, so that someone who might come by the Q&A in the future would have sufficient context to understand the answer.